# Find a generating function for $\sum_{k=0}^{n} k^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

> Find a generating function for $\sum_{k=0}^{n} k^2$

I know my solution is wrong, but why?

**My solution:**
If $F(x)$ generates $\sum_{k=0}^{n} k^2$ then $F(x)(1-x)$ generates $k^2$.

$\frac{x}{(1-x)^4}: \left\{ 0,1,4,9,16,25...  \right\}$
$\frac{x}{(1-x)^3}: \left\{ 0,1,3,5,7,9...  \right\}$
$\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}: \left\{ 0,1,2,2,2,2...  \right\}$
$\frac{x}{1-x}: \left\{ 0,1,1,1,1,1...  \right\}$
$x: \left\{ 0,1,0,0,0,0...  \right\}$

So, $F(x)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^5}$ generates $\sum_{k=0}^{n} k^2$

Comment: The sum diverges; also it's a single expression and not a sequence. Perhaps you mean "find a generating function for $\sum_{k=0}^{n} k^2$".

Comment: Yes, You are right. Let me correct this.

Comment: What is the meaning of the line containing {0,1,2,2,2,2...}?

Comment: Those are the coefficients of $\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$. In other words, this is the sequence $a_n$ generated by $\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$.

Comment: The differences of $\{0,1,2,2,2,2,\dots\}$ are $\{0,1,1,0,0,\dotsc\}$, not $\{0,1,1,1,1,\dotsc\}$.

Comment: Oh man.. What a rookie mistake! Thank you @DanielFischer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The differences of $\{0,1,2,2,2,2,\dots\}$ are $\{0,1,1,0,0,\dotsc\}$, not $\{0,1,1,1,1,\dotsc\}$.

So you should get

$$\begin{align}
x+x^2 &: \{0,1,1,0,0,\dotsc\}\\
\frac{x+x^2}{1-x} &: \{ 0,1,2,2,2,\dotsc\}\\
\frac{x+x^2}{(1-x)^2} &: \{ 0,1,3,5,7,\dotsc\}\\
\frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3} &: \{ 0,1,4,9,\dotsc\}
\end{align}$$

and

$$\frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^4}$$

as the generating function of $\sum k^2$.

Answer (score 4):

Just consider:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} z^n
  &= \frac{1}{1 - z} \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} n^2 z^n
  &= z \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} 
       \left( z \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} \frac{1}{1 - z} \right) \\
  &= \frac{z + z^2}{(1 - z)^3} \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} \left( \sum_{0 \le k \le n} k^2 \right) z^n
  &= \frac{z + z^2}{(1 - z)^4}
\end{align}
Just for the heck of it:
\begin{align}
\sum_{0 \le k \le n} k^2
  &= [z^n] \frac{z + z^2}{(1 - z)^4} \\
  &= [z^{n - 1}] (1 - z)^{-4} + [z^{n - 2}] (1 - z)^{-4} \\
  &= (-1)^{n - 1} \binom{-4}{n - 1} + (-1)^{n - 2} \binom{-4}{n - 2} \\
  &= \binom{n - 1 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} + \binom{n - 2 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} \\
  &= \binom{n + 2}{3} + \binom{n + 1}{3} \\
  &= \frac{(n + 2) (n + 1) n + (n + 1) n (n - 1)}{3!} \\
  &= \frac{(2 n + 1) (n + 1) n}{6}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a cubic polynomial of the general form $an^3+bn^2+cn+d$.  You can solve for the coefficients by plugging in a couple different values of n.  Then solve the system of equations! A matrix would work nicely. This is really a brute force type thing. I can write up a more elegant solution if you like.

Comment: Hmm.. thank you but I prefer using generating-function "tools".

Comment: What do you mean @AnnieOK

Answer (score 1):

According to the example, how to get the [generating function for squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Ordinary_generating_functions) you can do the following:

Use $$
    \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+k}k x^n= \frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}} $$
and set
$$
a\binom{n+3}{3}+ b\binom{n+2}{2}+c\binom{n+1}{1}+d=\frac{n^3}{3}+\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac n2=\sum_{k=1}^n k^2
$$
You'll find [$a=2,b=-3,c=1$ and $d=0$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427eibrdjl2pon). So
$$
\frac{2}{(1-x)^4}-\frac{3}{(1-x)^3}+\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}
$$
is the [generating function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427edgiu6vm513), which sums up to Daniel's answer...